# JVM Heap usage charts interpretation

Tags: memory-usage, memory-leak, jvm

I'd like to ask for some tips how should I concern different JAVA apps memory usage line charts. Should I find any of them as "memory leak"? How my JVM profiling impacts on GC activity?

Each of them shows selected application under different load intensity and characteristic.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server.
All apps run with

- -server
- -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote options.

Monitoring based on **collectd** and JMX. JVM heap memory used.

APP_2 : Xmx 750MB, Parallel GC with 2 thread(s)

[image]

- no user requests
- high-memory consume, aggregation jobs

APP_4 : Xmx 500MB, Mark Sweep Compact GC

[image]

- almost zero activity
- diagnostic tasks

Comment: A memory leak would imply continuous growth and new highs over time, where is that happening in these data?  Also, try getting performance and response time data from the applications, that's what really matters.

Comment: None of them? So you suggest that both are acceptable? What about intensity of GC?

Comment: I'm not suggesting any conclusion, just that you need more data about the application to tell if its performance is affected.